# February 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's been 8 months since the last election on Stack Overflow. The site continues to grow, and with it the need for dedicated moderators. With over 1900 flags a day, the need for folks able and willing to devote some time to [handling those exceptions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) has never been greater.

So today we're kicking off [**The Spring 2013 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election**](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Elections generally last three weeks, one week per phase. Visit

### https://stackoverflow.com/election

...for details and to participate.

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

If you want to talk about the election, the candidates, the process, or waffles (as they relate to elections), drop into the [Stack Overflow Election Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24975/2013-stack-overflow-moderator-election).

#### New this year: links to candidate review history

Folks often ask, "What does being a moderator require?" Well, on Stack Overflow, handling flags is the single biggest part of the job. Folks identify potential problems and flag them; a moderator needs to be able to quickly evaluate the situation, decide if action is required, and make it happen. This is also pretty close to the tasks given to folks reviewing posts in [Stack Overflow's Community Review Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/review) - in recognition of this, we've added links to each candidate's history of reviews to the nominations. Want to see the sort of dedication and decision-making you might expect from a candate? Look at the moderation they've already been doing!

[image: Link to review history]

Comment: Spring sure came early this year.

Comment: It's been a long, hard winter of discontent

Comment: Given the emphasis on "review history" in this post I was expecting a new page with nice aggregate statistics, such as audit success/fail/rate, breakdowns by categories of reviews, number and % approval of suggested edits, % of "do nothing" or "acceptable" in relevant queues, skip rate, and so on.  The history tab, other than giving a number of reviews and possibly some info on the last dozen or so, isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @Servy: Because we all know how accurate the review audits are. *rolls eyes*

Comment: @animuson Well, it would be better than knowing nothing.  For example a 0% audit success rate is one heck of a red flag, no matter how bad the audits are.  Low absolute numbers of audits compared to total reviews means they haven't been reviewing recently, they've done more in the past.

Comment: @Servy We thought about that and decided that trying to meaningfully aggregate and compare review results like that was, at best, difficult. If you want to learn about a candidate's behaviour, you're far better off looking at their specific history rather than a few summarized numbers.

Comment: @Shog9 The problem here is more with the first two stages where there are *lots* of candidates.  You can't realistically spend the time needed looking at specific reviews, in large enough quantity, to learn anything.  Aggregate results could potentially allow you to put people into buckets of "almost certainly good", "obviously terrible", and "inconclusive".  In later stages, there's really no choice but to look at specific reviews, but aggregate data would allow you to filter out obviously poor candidates.

Comment: How do I nominate someone else? I've seen this person <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man">The Tin Man</a> providing excellent ongoing help to many developers here. His edits and answers are clear, skilled, helpful, and well-written. I believe he can be a great moderator if he wants the role.

Comment: The only nominations are self-nominations, @joel. Also be aware that moderator duties are pretty much completely unrelated to answering questions.

Comment: @joshcaswell you should nominate yourself!

Comment: @Servy: I regularly look at quite a bit of aggregate information on reviewers... That's great for picking out certain problems. It's also incredibly misleading when you're comparing individuals: two people can have very similar stats (in terms of number of reviews, decisions made, even audit failures) and yet *vastly* different styles when it comes down to the actual decisions they make. If you want to know what someone's doing when moderating the site, there's no substitute for actually looking at that in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the vote, @BenTrengrove, but I waste too m...ahem! am trying to spend a little _less_ time on SO these days, rather than more. I can't commit to the [standard of duty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/).

Comment: Unfortunately the [More information about the candidates](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow) web app is b0rken at the moment. I get a JS error both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe this question had to be on meta.stackoverflow?