# Should we close old moderator election threads?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, moderator-election

Right now, we have a lot of old announcements related to long-past moderator elections. Some of them have been closed as "can no longer be reproduced" (e.g. *[Autumn 2015 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309752/autumn-2015-community-moderator-election)*, *[November 2011 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287860/november-2011-community-moderator-election)*, and *[2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)*), while many remain open, such as *[February 2013 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274909/february-2013-community-moderator-election)*, *[2017 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354232/2017-community-moderator-election-results)*, *[Spring 2018 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365198/spring-2018-community-moderator-election-results)*, and *[November 2016 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338289/november-2016-community-moderator-election-results)*.

When is it appropriate to close an old moderator election question?

- Should these stay open in perpetuity?
- Should they be immediately closed after a reasonable amount of time has passed since the election (and how much time is "reasonable"? 72 hours? A week? A month? A year? Geologic time?)?
- Should they be closed after it becomes clear that the discussion has "run its course" and that no one else is likely to have anything to share?

A big part of me thinks that it doesn't make *sense* for these questions to stay open, any more than it would be to have an ongoing "Dukakis '88" forum, but then it also occurred to me that keeping these old threads open is not obviously *harmful* per se, as we tend to get relatively little spam, "me too", and other flaggable garbage answers here on Meta.

Comment: Notice that not a single one of the closed questions was closed by a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

Closing is nomination for deletion. It is not an indicator that the discussion has "run its course".

Those announcements should not be deleted; therefore, they should not be closed.

Comment: "[Closing] is not an indicator that the discussion has 'run its course'." Yes, and this applies not just to meta but to the main site as well. You do not close questions that have "run their course". Not every question comes with an expiry date that renders it suddenly no longer on-topic for the site.